# Playa not displaying entries from different site within multi site manager

Tags: playa, multi-site-manager

I have site 1 and site 2.

Site 2 has a Playa field related to a channel in site 1. I cannot get the related entries from site 1 to display in site 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **site="site_short_name"** to the Playa tag.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" ...}
    {related_field site="site_1"}
        {some_field}<br>
    {/related_field_name}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Note: as of today, this is not included anywhere in Playa's documentation.